# Removing the spaces in Jinja2 tables

Tags: jinja2

I have a table and I am creating two values in one td and I want that two values should get fit into the one column header.
I am showing what did I try here

```
<table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Email</th>
                    <th scope="col">Study time</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for each_detail in result %}

                <tr>
                    <td>{{ each_detail.student_name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ each_detail.student_email }}</td>
                    {% for each_time in each_detail.time %}
                    <td style="padding-left: 0px;">{{ each_time['starttime'] }}-{{ each_time['endtime'] }}</td>
                    {% endfor %}


                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>

        </table>
```

What is happening here is I have multiple values for study time column.All values should come under one column ie without much space. But the second study time slot is moving into another column.
I am attaching the image for reference.
[image: As per the image i have space between 14-19 and 21-23 but i dont need that]

Answer (score 0):

Including colspan="2" in the table of `<th colspan='2'>Study times</th>` solved the issue